# lat/long coordinates to pixel returning out of range indices

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, pixel, gdal

I have GeoDataFrame that contains multiple lat/long coordinates, these coordinates belong to a raster image and I'm trying to get the pixel (x, y) values for each lat/long. I have tried multiple approaches the last one was the following:

```
import affine
import numpy as np

def retrieve_pixel_value(geo_coord, data_source):
    """Return floating-point value that corresponds to given point."""
    x, y = geo_coord[0], geo_coord[1]

    forward_transform =  \
        affine.Affine.from_gdal(*data_source.GetGeoTransform())
    #print(forward_transform)
    
    reverse_transform = ~forward_transform
    #print(reverse_transform)
    px, py = reverse_transform * (x, y)
    print(px, py)
    px, py = int(px + 0.5), int(py + 0.5)
    print(px, py)
    pixel_coord = px, py

    data_array = np.array(data_source.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
    return data_array[pixel_coord[0]][pixel_coord[1]]
```

but I'm getting index out of range, which makes sense since the values of `pixel_coords[0]` and `pixel_coord[1]` are `(-1465570, 7463711)`
I also tried another approach and had the same results

I have to say I have a basic understanding of working with GIS data, but I'm not quite comfortable with this concept, yet.
Why I'm getting Index out of range?
Also is there a way to implement with other libraries than GDAL?

Comment: ... I just had a very quick look... but as I see it your `pixel_coord` represents x- and y- coordinates and not indices in the array right?   so you still need to transform your x-y coordinates into row&column to be able to use it to index your `data_array`........... here are several other methods that might do what you want: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299787/finding-pixel-location-in-raster-using-coordinates

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. It seems exactly what I need